# Using MFC macros with templates

Tags: c++, templates, mfc

Is it possible to derive and use a C++ template class from a MFC class such as CDialog.  I've tried, but the implementation falls over with the MFC macros used for message routing.  For example;

```
template<class TYPE, class ARG_TYPE>
class CMyDialogT : public CDialog
{
public:
    CMyDialogT(CMyContainerT<TYPE,ARG_TYPE> *pData,CWnd* pParent = NULL);  
    CMyContainerT<TYPE,ARG_TYPE> *m_pData;
    // Generated message map functions
    //{{AFX_MSG(CMyDialogT)
    afx_msg void OnUpdateMyControl();
    //}}AFX_MSG
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

template<class TYPE, class ARG_TYPE>
CMyDialogT<TYPE,ARG_TYPE>::CMyDialogT(CMyContainerT<TYPE,ARG_TYPE> *pData,CWnd* pParent)
    : CDialog(CMyDialogT::IDD, pParent)
{
    m_pData = pData;
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CGlobalEditT<TYPE,ARG_TYPE>, CDialog)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CGlobalEditT)
    ON_EN_UPDATE(IDC_MY_CONTROL, OnUpdateMyControl)
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

The above fails to compile with a sequence of messages starting as follows;

```
 warning C4002: too many actual parameters for macro 'BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP'
 error C2653: 'TYPE' : is not a class or namespace name
```

Is there any workaround for this, other than manually unrolling the MFC macros?  I can't use template specialisation at this point, as given in a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004870/can-a-custom-mfc-window-dialog-be-a-class-template-instantiation) as I don't know all the possible values of TYPE and ARG_TYPE.

Another way of looking at the question would be 'can I embed a template class in another class without either specialising the template or making the host class a template class'.  I can't answer this one either, I suspect the answer may be No.

**Edit**  Partial solution for single type templates on [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa986916%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The more general problem of macros and templates is because *Macros are Stupid* (tm).

The preprocessor does not care for `<>` or `[]` as grouping operators, therefore when parsing the macro invocation:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CGlobalEditT<TYPE,ARG_TYPE>, CDialog)
```

It translates to:

- Macro name: `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP`
- Argument 1: `CGlobalEditT<TYPE`
- Argument 2: `ARG_TYPE>`
- Argument 3: `CDialog`

Then looks up the definition of `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP`, realizes it is a macro with only 2 arguments, and complains lowdly.

There are two types of situations in which this can happen:

- within a class or a function
- to actually declare a template class or a template function

In the latter case, you are more or less screwed, unless specific macros are provided.

In the former case, you have two solutions:

- Using a `typedef` to provide a synonym to `CGlobalEditT<TYPE,ARG_TYPE>` that does not contain a comma
- Using braces around `CGlobalEditT<TYPE,ARG_TYPE>` to "isolate" the comma

When braces work, it's great, however it's not always the case.

When they don't, `typedef` is often a suitable alternative.

In any case, it is something to keep in mind about macros.

Answer (score 6):

You have to use BEGIN_TEMPLATE_MESSAGE_MAP instead of BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP.

Comment: +1 thanks, but it doesn't work with more than one template argument, as in the sample code above.

Comment: I didn't check your code, sorry...I just read message map and templates and thought about BEGIN_TEMPLATE_MESSAGE_MAP. Anyway, good to know you solved your problem!